# ScrewTurn Wiki Active Directory Support

Tags: asp.net, screwturn

### Environment

- ScrewTurn Wiki (most recent stable build)
- Windows 7 x64
- IIS 7

**The wiki is currently installed on my development box while we provision a server.**

### Configuration

```
GroupMap=ABC GROUP:Administrators
```

**It is in fact *two* words like it looks.**

So I installed ScrewTurn Wiki as well as the commonly accepted [Active Directory Provider](http://www.screwturn.eu/Customize.Active-Directory-Provider.ashx) for it. And last week everything was working really well. When new users that existed in the domain group hit the site a new STW user was created and setup in the right group. Further, when ***I*** hit the site it logged me in with my AD credentials.

**However, when I hit the site today it's not logging me in with my AD credentials.**

*To add insult to injury, my peers are logging in just fine with their AD credentials.*

I looked at the plug-in through the administration console it says `Error` in the `Update Status` column. Could that be causing my issue?

**Could it be that it's running on my development box? That doesn't make sense because it was working last week - but it's worth asking.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hopefully if anybody runs across this - this will help. The issue is that STW creates an actual user. I know that kind of goes without saying - but in my case I was logging in and out as `admin` as well to administer some other things on my box.

Because of that it wasn't caching the logged in user as my AD user. When I logged in with my AD user name and password through the login screen it leveraged the AD authentication and logged me in as expected. But I did in fact have to login manually.